# Password invalid

Tags: password, data-recovery

I tried the process recommended, but was unable to reset the Password. regardless of what I typed, the results were always "root@jimmie-z62FM:~#". I tried adding or deleting spaces and would sometimes get "command not found". I am not going to fiddle with this command input frustration. I am going to reformat and start over from scratch.

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu (Rank, uninformed Newbie). Installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS onto old laptop. The installation apparently lifted an old (also, apparently) forgotten password. "password invalid" message with every key combination. I used the installation disc in attempt to get a command line but I get to the "Install (as superuser) Wireless" screen that does not respond to any input. How do I access the proper commands to reset password? I never got the option to burn a recovery disc when I installed.

Comment: Password does not appear on screen, when you enter it in terminal, even like ****. Just enter it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things to check is to confirm that your Number Lock isn't on when you're trying your password. If this isn't the case @user68186 is correct, you can use the link to reset your password:

[How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)